# trying to get age from date of birth

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
SELECT [ID_KUNDNR]
      ,CASE
       WHEN DA_FODELSEAR IS NULL THEN 0
       WHEN dateadd(year, datediff (year, DA_FODELSEAR, getdate()), DA_FODELSEAR) > getdate() THEN datediff (year, DA_FODELSEAR, getdate()) - 1
       ELSE datediff (year, DA_FODELSEAR, getdate())
       END As Age
      ,[Catalog]
  FROM Table
```

I get

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting
>   expression to data type datetime.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just wondering why you are using case.  Try the below and see whether it works.

```
 SELECT [ID_KUNDNR] ,
    datediff (year, 0, (getdate()-DA_FODELSEAR)) as Age,
    Catalog
    From Table
```

But again are you sure all values of DA_FODELSEAR is convertable to datetime?

If you have trouble try this.

```
 SELECT [ID_KUNDNR] ,
    Case When ISDATE(DA_FODELSEAR) = 0 Then 0 Else
        datediff (year, 0, (getdate()-DA_FODELSEAR)) 
        End as Age,
    Catalog
    From Table
```

Incase you want to know, which rows are causing this conversion problem select the table with **'where IsDATE(DA_FODELSEAR) = 0'**

Comment: DA_FODELSEAR is nvarchar type.

Comment: I understand but   Select Datediff(year, 0, (getdate() - '1980-01-45')) fails.  Or it could be some problems with the date format stored in DB.  What is the format you are using in DA_FODELSEAR

Comment: @vovkjn: Also, `datetime` can hold dates no earlier than `1753-01-01` and no later than `9999-12-31`. You need to make sure, if you haven't done that yet, that `DA_FODELSEAR` doesn't contain any dates outside those bounds.

Comment: SUPERB! That example "Case When ISDATE(DA_FODELSEAR) = 0 Then 0 Else
        datediff (year, 0, (getdate()-DA_FODELSEAR)) 
        End as Age"

Comment: Thanks... But please be aware that invalid dates will have 0 as Age

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem lies here `dateadd(year, datediff(year, DA_FODELSEAR, getdate()), DA_FODELSEAR)`.  You have a value in your `DA_FODELSEAR` that is not in a `DATETIME` format.  I would run a `SELECT` statement to find the offending value.  You are checking for `NULL` but what about a blank space?

Comment: there are some values like 0000.

Comment: @vovkjn: That will be one cause of your problem.  If they aren't needed, I'd suggest `null`ing them out.

Comment: @vovkjn: please tick the hollow tick to the left to mark as answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that `DA_FODELSEAR` is in correct datetime format. You can do it by using `CAST(DA_FODELSEAR as DATETIME)` and check.

Comment: I just did it. And get the same error. However DA_FODELSEAR is an integer.

Comment: Sorry. DA_FODELSEAR is nvarchar.

Comment: @vovkjn - hmmm ok, thought so. nvarchar makes sense. Some data in that column is not in proper datetime format and that is causing this error.

Comment: @vovkjn - You have to weed out all such data from DA_FODELSEAR column which are not in datetime format.